# Opened in new tab issue while clicking on sub-menu in every test (Selenium-java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

While running the script in selenium we are clicking on the sub-menu in every test some times that sub-menu opened in new tab.
Ex: we are running the 6 scenarios, 3 are opened in same tab and remaining 3 are opened in new tabs.

It should open in new tab.

Comment: You can open them all in a new TAB. Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: please add more details, what you are trying to do and achieve.